# which Micro-Frameworks can I try online?

Tags: php, python, web-frameworks

I see that we can try Flask (the python micro framework from the browser, well... kind of), is there any other microframework that can be tested online before using it in a project?

It is ok for me, if the micro framework is in any of the following languages (php, ruby, python, javascript, clojure, erlang or haskell)

Comment: That's quite a cool idea actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean try online? Like write code to some page and test it? I really don't see a point in that. You often need at least two files for meaningful testing. If you want to just see results of the framework I'd guess that its project page is written in it.

If the first one is the case, use bundled testing webserver. Many frameworks do have one. For example [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) (it's for python) has one and there is no configuration needed. Just paste sample hello world code, run the script and it will work. You can then continue from that.